# how to fetch two document array's user defined properties in DocumentDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My 1st document contains following properties

```
{  
  "id":"123456789",
  "sensordata1":[  
     {  
        "Time":"8:16:19",
        "Temperature":27.9,
        "Humidity":96.5,
        "Voltage":0.03,
        "Current":0.5
     }]
```

My second document contains following properties

```
{  
    "id":"987654321",
    "sensordata2":
    {  
        "Time":"8:17:14",
        "Temperature":31.7,
        "Humidity":81.2,
        "Voltage":1.44,
        "Current":0.25
     }]
```

I want both document user defined properties but don't want system defined properties(like etags,attachment and all).

For Fetching user define data i have used the following query.

```
select e.Time,
       e.Temperature,
       e.Humidity,
       e.Voltage,
       e.Current,
       g.Time,
       g.Temperature,
       g.Humidity,
       g.Voltage 
from Items f 
     join e in f.sensordata1 join g in s.sensordata2
```

but it returns the empty array as result. How do i change the query to get desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the `JOIN` operation. In Cosmos DB it's used for intra-document join, e.g. to combine data from document properties to fields of sub-array inside the same document. You can't use join to combine two documents.

The easiest way is just to query all the fields all the time, and then combine non-empty fields in your code.

If you really need to combine two documents in such way inside the database, you could write a user-defined function, which would query two documents by ID and then combine them.

Comment: I need only user defined properties and don't want system defined properties(like rid,self,etag,attachments,ts and all).
How to query to get the desired result?

Comment: Finally, i found the solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9ba4d0a7-64f1-45e5-955d-75989ec142e7/can-i-get-document-without-document-db-metadata-properties?forum=AzureDocumentDB